# Connect to server assigned Private IP on Ubuntu Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I hope I'm asking this clearly. I connected to a fresh Ubuntu 64-bit Amazon EC2 server with SSH and have set up a Server that uses the IP 172.30.0.72:27015 and it is ONLINE, and my Amazon Security is set to allow all ports.

When I type `netstat -atunp | grep srcds_linux` it shows:

```
tcp   0   0     0 172.30.0.72:27015   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  1277/sccds_linux
udp   0   0     0 172.30.0.72:27015   0.0.0.0:*          1277/sccds_linux
udp   0   0     0 172.30.0.72:26901   0.0.0.0:*          1277/sccds_linux
```

When I try to access this from outside, I can't. Do I need to be figuring out how to port forward? If so, I know my public IP is 55.174.94.92, how do I connect my client to the server that has the Private IP address? I also know how to make it static with elastic IP's, but haven't done that until I get this to work first.

Comment: If you can't access it... how are you connecting to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the public IP to connect. To access your service at 172.30.0.72:27015 use 55.174.94.92:27015.
If you are no able to do it, then check your security group settings.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried to connect to the public IP, but didn't think to add the port. It seems to work. I thought I was going to have to manually configure the port to forward, but it must be built in.